# Reading curl response into variable/object

Tags: python, json, curl

I'm trying to get the json response from a curl post into a json object so I can get to the key/value pair inside the json response.

My attempt so far looks something like this:

```
import pycurl
import json
c = pycurl.Curl()
#c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True)
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://some.place/get/token')
c.setopt(c.FOLLOWLOCATION, True)
post_data = {'id': '1q2w3e4r5t',
         'secret': 'abcdefghij'}
# Form data must be provided already urlencoded.
postfields = urlencode(post_data)
# Sets request method to POST,
# Content-Type header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded
# and data to send in request body.
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, postfields)
c.perform()
c.close()
```

This pumps out the json to the terminal screen, but any attempts so far to "get" the actual json returned by the curl command fails. Ideally, I do NOT want to write the json repsonse into a file first, and I'm also not sure if I would be able to "listen" to stdin - as soon as I get this right, it will probably be transformed into a AWS lambda script...

I'm omitting some functions from my actual code - like the encoding etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a buffer and configure your `Curl` instance to write to it. Then you can read it and deserialize it.

```
import io

buffer = io.BytesIO()
# ... Initialize your Curl() instance as you did
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.perform()

data = json.loads(buffer.getvalue())
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect!